# Specify File path in tkinter File dialog

Tags: python, tkinter, filedialog

I have a file dialog to open a file, however, the file that I want to open is in a different directory than the program I wrote.  The file dialog opens to the directory where I am.  Is there a way to specify where the filedialog opens?

Here is the relevant code:

```
root = Tk()
root.fileName = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
f = open(root.fileName, 'r')
```

I tried adding the path that I want into the "askopenfilename" call, but that didn't work:

```
root.fileName = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename('/C:')
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you want is:

```
root.fileName = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:/<whatever>")
```

This argument will allow you to specify the directory to which the window will open up.